# PHP : Convert a string to an array

Tags: php, arrays

How can I convert String to an Array?

String bellow

```
$string = "12&Shoes&28&Jewelry&30&Watch&96&Beauty&98&Kids&Baby";
```

wants to output:

```
 array{
        [12] => 'Shoes',
        [28] => 'Jewelry',
        [30] => 'Watch',
        [96] => 'Beauty',
        [98] => 'Kids&Baby'
    }
```

Can any one suggest me how can I convert it using php function? like preg_match,preg_match_all etc.also code should be short.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: @manian Thanks But yet I have no more Idea how can I convert it.

Comment: Explode give me like single array. like Array ( [0] => 12 [1] => Shoes [2] => 28 [3] => Jewelry [4] => 30 [5] => Watch [6] => 96 [7] => Beauty [8] => 98 [9] => Kids [10] => Baby )

Comment: This will be very hard as the string does not follow any pattern. May be you can identify integer & string to split

Comment: This will be very hard as the string does not follow any pattern. May be you can identify integer & string to split

Comment: Since the string contains "Kids&Baby", I am not sure if any of the answer so far will give exact results

Comment: @manian for "Kids&Baby" we can use str_replace for it Like    $string = "12&Shoes&28&Jewelry&30&Watch&96&Beauty&98&Kids&Baby";
$string = str_replace('Kids&Baby','Kids_Baby',$string); // Output will be "12&Shoes&28&Jewelry&30&Watch&96&Beauty&98&Kids_Baby" So "Kids&Baby" will be not meter.

Comment: @RP, try my solution with preg_match_all. I'm trying to figure out how to remove the last & sign, it's been a long time regexp :)

Comment: @RP, just posted an answer with few lines of code as you expected.

Comment: @manian Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks to all to give me answer and best reply.

Answer (score 3):

I know you asked for regex, but i'm the one who likes to do other way if it's simple to do.

```
$string = "12&Shoes&28&Jewelry&30&Watch&96&Beauty&98&Kids&Baby&Try";
$array = explode('&', $string);
$total = count($array);
for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
  if (is_numeric($array[$i])) {
   $result[$array[$i]] = '';
   $lastIndex = $array[$i];
  } else {
    if ($result[$lastIndex] == ''){
       $result[$lastIndex] .= $array[$i];
    } else {
        $result[$lastIndex] .= '&' . $array[$i];
    }
  }
}
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: My first thought, but wouldn't work because of the "Kids&Baby".

Comment: @mighTY Done! ;)

Comment: Great its Done. Can we optimize it?

Comment: Yeah, im doing that, wait plz

Comment: can you explain how you fixed Kids&Baby? :D

Comment: @skunkhaze The previous code was complicated I simplified that, review plz. I'm at work, sry if I couldn't do best

Comment: @CarlosAlexandre I think the previous edit was way cleaner. But It's up to you how to leave it.

Comment: @mighTY With that way we can rely on the code all of parsing between indexes and content and only spending one more var, no much costs. The previous code wasn't optimized as R P stated above. If the string take more than 3 or 4 strings, it would be a problem. I open to reviews too, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try next one:

```
$list = array();

// $tmp = explode('&', $string); - not suitable coz of 'Value&Value' existence 
preg_match_all('/\d+|[a-z&]+/i', $string, $tmp);
foreach ($tmp[0] as $i => $value) {
    // 0, 2, ... elements are the keys
    if ($i%2 === 0) {
        $key = $value;
    // 1, 3 ... values
    } else {
        $list[$key] = trim($value, '&');
    }
}
```

Or even shorter version:

```
preg_match_all('/(\d+)\&([a-z&]+[^\&0-9])/i', $string, $tmp);
$list = array_combine($tmp[1], $tmp[2]);
```

Result:

```
var_dump($list);

array(5) {
  [12] => string(5) "Shoes"
  [28] => string(7) "Jewelry"
  [30] => string(5) "Watch"
  [96] => string(6) "Beauty"
  [98] => string(9) "Kids&Baby"
}
```

Comment: Thank for reply and try. code give me Warning Like                                   
- Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in D:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 11
- Warning: Illegal offset type in D:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 11

Comment: @RP, it was true before last edit (`foreach ($tmp` -> `foreach ($tmp[0]` )

Comment: Even shorter would be: `preg_match_all('/(\d+)\&([a-z&]+[^\&0-9])/i', $string, $tmp);
$list = array_combine($tmp[1], $tmp[2]);`

Answer (score 1):

Please try PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE with preg_split to get the items which was split ,

```
$string = "12&Shoes&28&Jewelry&30&Watch&96&Beauty&98&Kids&Baby";

$array = preg_split("/(\d+)/", $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
foreach($array AS $key => $val) {
   if($key%2) continue;
   $result[$val] = trim($array[$key+1], '&');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed my previous answer, since I suggested `parse_str`, but I didn't read the question correctly.

One solution could be, using preg_match_all.
The only problem is, I can't filter out the last & at the end of each value. Trying to figure out how regexp non-matching works again :)

**NOTE!** This isn't going to work if your values contain numbers!

```
php > preg_match_all('/(?P<key>[0-9]+)&(?P<values>[^0-9]+)/i', $string, $matches);
php > var_dump($matches);
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "12&Shoes&"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "28&Jewelry&"
    [2]=>
    string(9) "30&Watch&"
    [3]=>
    string(10) "96&Beauty&"
    [4]=>
    string(12) "98&Kids&Baby"
  }
  ["key"]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "12"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "28"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "30"
    [3]=>
    string(2) "96"
    [4]=>
    string(2) "98"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "12"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "28"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "30"
    [3]=>
    string(2) "96"
    [4]=>
    string(2) "98"
  }
  ["values"]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "Shoes&"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "Jewelry&"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "Watch&"
    [3]=>
    string(7) "Beauty&"
    [4]=>
    string(9) "Kids&Baby"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "Shoes&"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "Jewelry&"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "Watch&"
    [3]=>
    string(7) "Beauty&"
    [4]=>
    string(9) "Kids&Baby"
  }
}
```

Comment: My apologies, I scanned your string to fast and didn't notice it isn't a valid parameter=value combination, like you use in URL's. So my solution isn't going to work. It would have worked if you strings looks like: `$string = "12=Shoes&28=Jewelry&30=Watch&96=Beauty&98=Kids&Baby";`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my improvement to @FieryCat's snippets.

To accommodate `Kids&Baby`, just make it optional for a "value" component to contain a `&` if it is immediately followed by letters.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/PqDQZ))

```
$string = "12&Shoes&28&Jewelry&30&Watch&96&Beauty&98&Kids&Baby";

var_export(
    preg_match_all(
        '/(\d+)&([a-z]+(?:&[a-z]+)?)/i',
        $string,
        $m
    )
    ? array_combine($m[1], $m[2])
    : []
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  12 => 'Shoes',
  28 => 'Jewelry',
  30 => 'Watch',
  96 => 'Beauty',
  98 => 'Kids&Baby',
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
function trim_custom($item){
  return trim($item,'&');
}

$string = "12&Shoes&28&Jewelry&30&Watch&96&Beauty&98&Kids&Baby";
$values = array_filter( explode(",",preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z-&]+/", ",", $string)) );
$values = array_map('trim_custom',$values);
$keys = array_filter ( explode(",",preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", ",", $string)) );

$list = array_combine($keys,$values);
```

Output:

```
print_r($list);

Array
(
    [12] => Shoes
    [28] => Jewelry
    [30] => Watch
    [96] => Beauty
    [98] => Kids&Baby
)
```

Comment: Kids&Baby is one value though

Comment: @Ali Hesari thanks. but in last "Kids&Bab" will be a problem.

Comment: @RP I've fixed function